# Copying a git repo via a USB drive causes all files to show as modified

Tags: linux, git, macos

I have been working on some code on my mac and want to start working on it on my linux desktop. The project is managed under git. Before the copy, I made sure everything was committed. I then copied the folder containing everything from my mac onto a usb drive, then copied the folder from the usb drive to the linux box. After the copy, everything looks like it is where it should be, but if I do a git status all the files show up as modified. I'm guessing this is because the timestamps on the files have changed. Is their a way to retain the old timestamps so the files dont appear modified? Or to tell git to not worry about changes since the last commit? I'd prefer not to do a git commit -a immediately after the transfer as I dont really want the move of boxes in my git history.

Comment: git doesn't care at all about file modification timestamps, I'd rather check line endings and/or filemodes (permissions)

Comment: It's a strange use-case to use `git` and still be copying files.  Why not keep the repo centrally and clone to each working tree like you're supposed to?

Comment: @RomainValeri filemodes were indeed the culprit here

Comment: @trojanfoe git bundle docs explain this. Its not normal workflow but does happen https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use clone (rather than copying worktrees around) to share repos.

If you cannot directly clone / fetch / push / pull between the two machines, then you could create a "bundle file" and copy *that*, instead of copying the actual repo.  (See the git bundle` docs or search for existing questions/answers about how to share a repo in this way.)

When crossing operating systems, there are still potential issues.  e.g. You'd want to think about how you want to handle line endings if crossing between OS's that have different default line ending rules - but mac and linux shouldn't have that issue anyway.

Comment: More digging turned up the issue was with file permissions getting messed up. I think this probably happened on the ntfs usb drive. So creating a bundle like you suggest - zipping up the folder, copying the bundle, then unzipping the bundle, sorted things out. Thanks!

Comment: It's good that you found a solution, but a ZIP is not the same thing as a bundle and is still not a procedure I recommend.  `git bundle` is a method for copying content and history within git's intended mechanisms and as such is a safe way to share among machines, whereas OS-level copying (even of ZIP files) is not.